# Why do maps tilt after georeferencing?

Tags: georeferencing

So this is a scanned map of a portion of Morocco.
This is the original map 
[image]

And , this is the map after georeferencing it

[image]

This map is now giving me the correct coordinates for the positions on it , but why did It tilt? I fail to understand the reason it tilted

Comment: Maybe you gave Ground Control Points in some other coordinate system than the CRS used in the printed map.

Comment: If the map gives you good coordinates, aka he position of objects from the map is in concordance with the position of objects in real life, it means that that is the correct position of the map and that's why it's tillted.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. You need to explain exactly how you did the georeferencing. Use **[Edit]**.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231249/georeferencing-transformation-types/231286#231286   You could try and do one online and see if you can compare between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Given how lines of longitude converge at the poles, when we say 'North is up', we need to define what we mean by 'up' (or indeed 'north'). Assuming that you have accurately georeferenced the image, then the rotation either exists in the original cartography or the projection you are currently displaying it in your GIS.

Note the little north arrow I can just make out towards the bottom left of the image.  The image is too fuzzy to read this but I see what appear to be three 'norths' on it. This is common in many maps and usually represents something akin to the following:

1. Grid North, which is the direction of a grid line which is parallel to the central meridian on the country's National Grid (or other local reference system).
2. True North, which is the direction of the actual North Pole.
3. Magnetic North, which is the direction shown by a compass. Magnetic North is not fixed but moves very slowly over time.

A map can be aligned to any of these (or south/something else in some cases!  North does not have to be at the top of the page).  In good cartography the direction and divergence of the cartographic north from true north should be shown (but I can't see which is which from your image). The intended use of the map may also influence which orientation is chosen.  Now, if you change the SRS of your GIS display after digitizing, your map may appear to tilt more or in yet another direction.

Another source of 'tilt' can come from how the map is printed on the page - including misalignment of the original printer and deformation of the paper after printing due to moisture, and creasing etc.

Answer (score 0):

The tilt is likely due to the projection being applied to the map after you georeferenced it. Depending on a map's projection, the same input lat-long points (like the control points you used in georeferencing too!) may visually appear in different places.

Example: Let's say your map was of a city somewhere in Washington state (top left corner of the image below). The original, un-georeferenced version of the map appears flat, with any horizontal lines in the map itself parallel with the top of the page (like the green Un-Projected states here). If you chose to apply the Lambert Conformal Conic projection to your georeferenced map, for example, that very same location would bend and tilt much like the blue-outlined Washington state is below, even though the raw XY coordinates are unchanged.

[image]

(I don't know if you used a conic projection for your Morocco map, but this is just an example. Other projections can create similar visual effects--which are often the intent of the person using the projection.)